# Is there any extension or some method to read xml file in netlogo? #netlogo

Tags: xml, netlogo

I want to know how can i read xml file in netlogo. I want my model to read input from xml file. is it possible?

Comment: @goodgest: that link only applies to BehaviorSpace experiment definitions. I don't think that's what Maria is looking for.

Comment: @Maria: to my knowledge, no such extension exists. It would be a useful addition to NetLogo if someone was willing to create one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, no such extension exists. It would be a useful addition to NetLogo if someone was willing to create one.